# Reutilizar procedimiento almacenado sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Estoy intentando volver a reutilizar el resultado de un procedimiento para no volver a llamarlo dos veces, ya que así tarda demasiado la consulta.

```
      select DW.dbo.procedimiento(CONVERT(char(10), FecLlamada, 103), 
                        CONVERT(char(5), HorLlamada, 108), 
                        CONVERT(char(10), FecContestada, 103), 
                        CONVERT(char(5), HorContestada, 108)) AS TiempoRespuestaMinutos
         (CASE WHEN Segmentacion >= 1 
                  AND Segmentacion <= 1.5 
                  AND 'TiempoRespuestaMinutos' > 150 
          THEN 0                          
          ELSE 1 END) AS CumplimientoTRG

      from llamadas
```

Donde pone 'TiempoRespuestaMinutos' es donde quiero poner lo que devuelve el procedimiento.

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué hace ese procedimiento que sea tan costoso? Pregunto porque, si de verdad ese procedimiento es costoso como dices, no creo que ganes tanto quitando una llamada del `SELECT`. Probablemente el costo real es el simple hecho que el procedimiento se llame desde el `SELECT`, porque entonces tiene que ejecutarse por lo menos 1 vez por registro en tu tabla. Dependiendo de qué hace tu procedmiento, probablemente hay una mejor opción para acelerar tu consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder hacer referencia al resultado del procedimiento en el `SELECT` sin tener que ejecutarlo una segunda vez, puedes hacer esto ejecutándolo dentro de una tabla derivada (o dentro una expresión de tabla común si prefieres):

```
select TiempoRespuestaMinutos,
       CASE WHEN Segmentacion >= 1 
                 AND Segmentacion <= 1.5 
                 AND TiempoRespuestaMinutos > 150 
            THEN 0                          
            ELSE 1 END AS CumplimientoTRG
  from (select Segmentacion,
               DW.dbo.procedimiento(CONVERT(char(10), FecLlamada, 103), 
                        CONVERT(char(5), HorLlamada, 108), 
                        CONVERT(char(10), FecContestada, 103), 
                        CONVERT(char(5), HorContestada, 108)) AS TiempoRespuestaMinutos
          from llamadas) t
```

... o si prefieres una expresión de tabla común:

```
;with cte as (
  select Segmentacion,
         DW.dbo.procedimiento(CONVERT(char(10), FecLlamada, 103), 
                 CONVERT(char(5), HorLlamada, 108), 
                 CONVERT(char(10), FecContestada, 103), 
                 CONVERT(char(5), HorContestada, 108)) AS TiempoRespuestaMinutos
    from llamadas
)
select TiempoRespuestaMinutos,
       CASE WHEN Segmentacion >= 1 
                 AND Segmentacion <= 1.5 
                 AND TiempoRespuestaMinutos > 150 
            THEN 0                          
            ELSE 1 END AS CumplimientoTRG
      from cte
```

Pero aunque esto te ahorre una llamada por registro devuelto de la tabla `llamadas`, siguen siendo varias llamadas en total. Si de verdad la ejecución del procedimiento cuesta tanto, probablemente la consulta seguirá tardando mucho.

Lo ideal sería evaluar lo que hace el procedimiento y ver si no hay una mejor forma de combinarla con la consulta principal.

Comment: el procedimiento básicamente lo que hace el calcular fechas de respuesta en función de horarios, etc. En sí en bastante costoso pero si se puede ahorrar una llamada por registro ya se optimarizaría muchísimo.Voy a probar tu respuesta pero paraece que con esto se solucionaría. Gracias!

Comment: Ok, pero toma en cuenta que si la lógica dentro del procedimiento no es excesivamente complicado y puede expresarse con una consulta SQL, es casi seguro que hay lugar para una optimización mucho mejor que esta.